# What is the right iam role to execute lambda in the console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-iam

I want to provide a freelancer the ability to test, debug and deploy lambda functions in the console.

However the roles i saw until now are very restrictive (only logging) or very wide like AWSLambdaFullAccess: full S3 access(?)

What is the right role here, or do i have to create a custom one?

Comment: It depends exactly what he/she is supposed to do. Should the person read S3 buckets, write them, create new ones, delete existing ones, and similar questions for any other AWS service.

Answer (score 3):

There are two sets of permissions here.

First, there are the **permissions that you are giving the freelancer**. These should be sufficient to test, debug and deploy the Lambda function. You might want to limit which functions they are allowed to edit (eg based on a prefix in the function name).

Second, there is the **IAM Role** that is associated with the Lambda function. This will need sufficient permission to perform whatever task the Lambda function doing (eg accessing Amazon S3).

The freelancer will probably need `iam:PassRole` permission to be able to select an IAM Role for the Lambda functions (or I wonder if you can set that, and they simply cannot edit the role?).

Be *very* careful when you assign the freelancer `iam:PassRole` permission because if you do not limit which roles they can pass to Lambda, then they can effectively gain access to *any* IAM Role in your system (including those for Admins). You should limit which Roles they can pass.